# Web Design: Return after clicking buy button

Tags: html, .net

I wonder what is the best practice when clicking the buy button on one of the items. I want it to look like the only thing that is happening is that the shopping cart is flashing one more item. What should I do to achive this. Should I send a lot of information through the POST action so that I can recreate the same page and scroll to the same place (which would be very inconvenient) or is there a smarter and better solution. I'm using Visual Studio and MVC 3

As you probably understand I'm quite new to web design even though I worked a little bit with it now and then the last 15 years.

Regards

Comment: as @Diodeus suggested You can use jquery in MVC to perform ajax functionality on your page.

Answer (score 1):

It is good practice to engineer your website so that it works correctly in a non js environment.  In this case your button will submit the form with a full page refresh.  Your page is reloaded and your shopping basket now indicates to the user that there is an extra item in it.

To make it a nicer experience for our user we can then use an AJAX call to enhance the submit action.

This can be done by writing an AJAX call in jQuery that fires on the click event of the button (or submit event of the form).

**Example using jQuery on form submit**

```
$('form').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); //prevents full post-back

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "\\somesite\endpoint",
      data: $(this).serialize()
    }).done(function( bacon ) {
       alert( "Receive: " + bacon );
    });
});
```

**MVC 3 Ajax Extensions**

MVC3 also has some AJAX extension methods to help us.  In particular `Ajax.BeginForm`

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm())
{
    /* Your form elements here */

    <input type="submit" value="OK" />
}
```

Here is a simple example on how to use it [How to use ajax beginform](http://shahvaibhav.com/how-to-use-ajax-beginform-in-mvc3-razor/)